# How can I make this more DRY?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  $('.btnSmall.mobileBtn.about').on('click', function(e){
    $('.about').css({'display': 'block'});
    $('.compareMobile').css({'display': 'none'});
    $('.mobileFeaturedStatments').css({'display':'none'});
    $('.mobileBtn').removeClass('activeBtn');
    $(this).addClass('activeBtn');
  });

  $('.btnSmall.mobileBtn.vS').on('click', function(e){
    $('.about').css('display', 'none');
    $('.compareMobile').css('display' , 'block');
    $('.mobileFeaturedStatments').css('display' , 'none');
    $('.mobileBtn').css({'background' : '#A6A8AB'});
    $(this).addClass('activeBtn');

  });

  $('.btnSmall.mobileBtn.trending').on('click', function(e){
    $('.about').css({'display': 'none'});
    $('.compareMobile').css({'display': 'none'});
    $('.mobileFeaturedStatments').css({'display':'block'});
    $('.mobileBtn').css({'background' : '#A6A8AB'});
    $(this).addClass('activeBtn');
  });
```

this works as expected, but I'm thinking there's some way I can remove some of this repetition. Maybe a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$('.btnSmall.mobileBtn.vS,.btnSmall.mobileBtn.about,.btnSmall.mobileBtn.trending).on('click', function(e){
  var isvs=$(this).is('.vS');
  var isabout=$(this).is('.about');
  var istrending=$(this).is('.trending');
  $('.about').css({'display':isabout ? 'block':'none'});
  $('.compareMobile').css({'display':isvs ? 'block':'none'});
  $('.mobileFeaturedStatments').css('display' , istrending ? 'block':'none');
  $('.mobileBtn').css({'background' : '#A6A8AB'});
  $(this).addClass('activeBtn');
});
```

Comment: awesome. didn't know you could use ternaries within the css.